# PHP 7.0.5 password_hash() error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm on PHP 7.0.5 with FastCGI and NGINX, in mode I want to hash my password for storage in the db... I'm using this code, but getting an error

```
    $hash = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()
call to function undefined. huh? I thought it was a native function

In my .htaccess file I have:

RewriteRule v1/(.*)$ v1/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

This redirects /v1/register to /v1/index.php

When I goto /v1/register the hash crashes and gives my undefined, BUT, if I go directly to /v1/index.php it works!?

Complete code on page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$hash = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 
echo "echo hash:" .$hash;
die;
```

Comment: It is. Are you sure this error isn't being generated by a different line in your code?

Comment: Okay, I can see from your update it's pretty clearly that function generating the error. Can you do `echo phpversion();` and make sure PHP 7 is actually being used?

Comment: adding some additional comments above...

Comment: I've removed the tag [tag:php-7] because you can't actually be using PHP 7 if you're getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost certain your server is not running what you think it is. `mod_fcgid` is an Apache module and `.htaccess` is also Apache specific so you are probably not running Nginx. The password hashing functions were added in PHP 5.5.0. I'm going to say that you are actually running an Apache server with PHP < 5.5.0. You need to use the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the password hashing functions.

Comment: FPM/FastCGI and php 7.0.5 from phpinfo(); 
in the server panel it says, 7.0.5 run php as FPM Application served by nginx

Comment: @NathanLeggatt and if you put `echo phpversion();` in the same script before the `password_hash()` line?

Comment: AH, very interesting.... ok, when I print out phpinfo ON THIS PAGE, it changes if I'm redirecting vs if I access it directly. Directly it says php 7, if I go via the htaccess redirect it changes to 5.

Comment: @NathanLeggatt It sounds like you potentially have a weird reverse-proxy set up somewhere. Maybe you are running Nginx in front of Apache?

Comment: I've asked the server team.